# Im trying to freeze my screen whats the code and variable?

Tags: pygame

if player.gameover == True: is the code  im using and I want to freeze my screen but I dont know the code or variable. Thank you for reading this.

I couldn't find anything please answer as soon as possible it's an assignment.